# unique multi-column sorting angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I need to do a multiple column sort.  It needs to be "High (Red - Not in example because it's a zero count)", "Medium (Orange)", "Low (Yellow)".. like the image below..

[image: Correct Sorting]

However, when I use Angular JS Sorting, I get the following..

[image: incorrect Sorting]

ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="pat in vm.patients.slice(((vm.tableParams.currentPage-1)*vm.tableParams.pageSize), ((vm.tableParams.currentPage)*vm.tableParams.pageSize)) | orderBy:vm.tableParams.sortType:vm.tableParams.sortReverse track by $index" ng-click="vm.showPatientDetail(pat.PatientNum)">
```

When the column header is clicked.

```
<th ng-click="vm.setSortType('')">
                    <span>
                        Other Alerts &nbsp;
                        <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>
                    </span>
                </th>
```

The setSortType function...

```
vm.setSortType = function (sortType) {
        vm.tableParams.sortReverse = !vm.tableParams.sortReverse;

        if (sortType == '') {
            vm.tableParams.sortType = "['AlertHighCount', 'AlertMediumCount', 'AlertLowCount']";
            return;
        }

        vm.tableParams.sortType = sortType; 
    }
```

sample data of vm.patients.  The AlertHighCount would be first, AlertMediumCOunt, then AlertLowCount

```
{
    "PatientNum": 56,
    "LastName": "Patient",
    "FirstName": "Demo",
    "PatientName": "Patient, Demo",
    "PatientBirthDate": "1942-12-12T00:00:00",
    "PrescribePhys": 0,
    "PhysicianFirstName": null,
    "PhysicianLastName": null,
    "TreatmentCount": 0,
    "AlertHighCount": 1,
    "AlertMediumCount": 2,
    "AlertLowCount": 0,
    "AlertLevel": 0,
    "DeviceType": 1,
    "PMSPatient": 0
  },
  {
    "PatientNum": 727,
    "LastName": "cat",
    "FirstName": "cat",
    "PatientName": "cat, cat",
    "PatientBirthDate": null,
    "PrescribePhys": 0,
    "PhysicianFirstName": null,
    "PhysicianLastName": null,
    "TreatmentCount": 0,
    "AlertHighCount": 0,
    "AlertMediumCount": 2,
    "AlertLowCount": 1,
    "AlertLevel": 0,
    "DeviceType": 1,
    "PMSPatient": 0
  },
  {
    "PatientNum": 1036,
    "LastName": "Cat",
    "FirstName": "Cat",
    "PatientName": "Cat, Cat",
    "PatientBirthDate": null,
    "PrescribePhys": 0,
    "PhysicianFirstName": null,
    "PhysicianLastName": null,
    "TreatmentCount": 0,
    "AlertHighCount": 0,
    "AlertMediumCount": 1,
    "AlertLowCount": 5,
    "AlertLevel": 0,
    "DeviceType": 1,
    "PMSPatient": 0
  },
  {
    "PatientNum": 1040,
    "LastName": "Cat",
    "FirstName": "Cat",
    "PatientName": "Cat, Cat",
    "PatientBirthDate": null,
    "PrescribePhys": 0,
    "PhysicianFirstName": null,
    "PhysicianLastName": null,
    "TreatmentCount": 0,
    "AlertHighCount": 0,
    "AlertMediumCount": 1,
    "AlertLowCount": 3,
    "AlertLevel": 0,
    "DeviceType": 1,
    "PMSPatient": 0
  }
```

Comment: Not clear what data is actually being sorted or how you intend to manage toggling these. A simplified demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) would help

Comment: There are 3 columns in each object called 'AlertHighCount', 'AlertMediumCount', 'AlertLowCount'.  By default, I need it to sort first by High, then Medium, then Low.  In the example above, High is missing because I hide it when count is zero..unfortunately it's the only sample data I have to work with..  If you look at the first image, you'll see it sorts Medium first, then Low. The second image is the sorting my code above is returning..

Comment: not hard to copy data sample from browser dev tool network or log a stringified object to console. We can't manipulate an image. You probably need to define an object in `vm.setSortType`

Comment: In the setSortType function, I set sortType = "['AlertHighCount', 'AlertMediumCount', 'AlertLowCount']";  And then apply it to the OrderType

Comment: Should be actual array though, not string. try just removing outer quotes

Comment: Ahhh, that did the trick!  Changing it to... vm.tableParams.sortType = ['AlertHighCount', 'AlertMediumCount', 'AlertLowCount'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wanting the orderby parameter to be an array not a string

Try

```
vm.tableParams.sortType = ['AlertHighCount', 'AlertMediumCount', 'AlertLowCount'];
```